# Ruby Gems Path Weirdness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've been chasing my tail on this problem for a couple days now and its further away than ever. I am running a Rails 3.1, Ruby 1.9, Gem 1.8.15, Linux RHEL 4 environment.

The simplified problem is that ruby 'require' (and rails) can't find all the gems my app needs. And it seems that the gems require can't find have a gem name different than the *.rb. For example, "require 'sass'" locates sass.rb.  But "require  'therubyracer'" fails to locate the v8.rb inside the lib. There is no file called 'therubyracer.rb'.   Same
with 'therubyrhino' - there is no'therubyrhino.rb' but there is a 'rhino.rb' in the lib.

Bundle install does not throw an error even when these gems are in my Gemfile.

Here is an example:

First, to demonstrate the gem is installed:

```
  >locate 'rhino.rb' 
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyrhino-1.73.1/lib/rhino.rb
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gems/therubyrhino-1.73.1/lib/rhino.rb
```

Even though 'therubyrhino' is installed, and in the path, and bundle worked, 'gem which' cannot find it.  And this gem is in the

same path as 'sass', below, which it can find.  Here is the error:

```
gem which 'therubyrhino'
  ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library therubyrhino
```

Note that gem can find the rhino.rb file inside the gem, so the path must be working.

```
>gem which rhino
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyrhino-1.73.1/lib/rhino.rb
```

Require doesn't like the rhino.rb though:

```
ruby -rubygems -e 'require "rhino"'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in  ` 
  require': no such file to load -- java (LoadError)
```

And it can't find the gem by name.

```
   ruby -rubygems -e 'require "therubyrhino"'
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in ` require': 
      no such file to load -- therubyrhino (LoadError) from 
     /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in ` require'
```

But as I mentioned, whith 'therubyrhino' in my Gemfile, Bundle install works.

Here is my gem path, which I am setting manually to test:

```
>export GEM_PATH=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gem

>gem env
  ...

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gem
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

And finally, here is a case where life is good and require works. All is well and the prefix of the gem name = lib name (.../sass/lib/sass.rb).  First we can see that the sass gem is installed:

```
 >locate sass.rb  
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.14/lib/sass.rb
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.1.4/vendor/sass/lib/sass.rb
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.1.4/lib/sass.rb
```

Can Gem find it? Yes.

```
 >gem which sass
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.1.4/lib/sass.rb
```

And does ruby 'require' work? Yes.

```
  >ruby -rubygems -e 'require "sass"' 
  (no error)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to load the gem with `gem` command before being able to `require` it. For instance :

```
$ irb
1.9.3p0 :001 > gem 'therubyracer'
 => true 
1.9.3p0 :002 > require 'v8'
 => true
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `therubyracer` in your `Gemfile`, then all you need to do in your app is `require 'v8'`. Or you can specify the lib it in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem "therubyracer", :require => 'v8'
```

If you use `Bundler.require`, the above line will call `require 'v8'` automatically.

Note that `therubyrhino` is for `jruby` only; you cannot use it with C Ruby (MRI).